# I cannot download wingide5 on my kali_linux VM

Tags: kali-linux

Alright so I posted a comment about this topic earlier but I still don't have any answers but I think I have more info for you guys to try to help me with. 
So my problem is that when I try to download WingIDE5 using the code below this happens.

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -i ~/Downloads/wingide5_5.0.9-1_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 323257 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wingide5_5.0.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wingide5 (5.0.9-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wingide5:
 wingide5 depends on libqt4-webkit (>=4.6.2); however:
  Package libqt4-webkit is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wingide5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing trigger for menu (2.1.47) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wingide5
```

So last time when I asked how to solve this somebody said to install libqt4-webkit using the code

```
apt-get install libqt4-webkit
```

I used this code and then it gave me this

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install libqt4-webkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libqt4-webkit is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libqtwebkit4

E: Package 'libqt4-webkit' has no installation candidate
```

After reading this I went and tried to install "libqtwebkit4" and this is what happened.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install libqtwebkit4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libqtwebkit4 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wingide5 : depends: libqt4-webkit (>=4.6.2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After I did this I then went and did a 'apt-get -f install', it then removed wingide5, so now that I installed libqtwebkit4 I tried to install wingide5 again but it still gave me the same results as when I tried to install wingide5 and it told me that I needed to install libqt4-webkit.  I don't know how I am supposed to download this, if you have any suggestions please help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. Apparently libqt4-webkit is now integrated in  libqtwebkit4 so all you need it already there. To install wingide5 you have two options:

1. dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libqt4-webkit wingide5_5.0.9-1_amd64.dep
2. Download the libqt4-webkit transitional package from Debian [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libqt4-webkit).

Comment: option number 1 worked!! Thank you so much!! You're a life saver